# Double occurrence of a column's values and update another column's value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

My dataset looks like this:

```
Country | ProductType 
USA     |    A        
China   |    B        
Japan   |    A        
Ireland |    B        
France  |    A
```

I need to duplicate the occurrence of each country and assign a corresponding value in the ProductType column to give each country both product A and B.

What I am looking for:

```
Country | ProductType
USA     | A
USA     | B
China   | A
China   | B
Japan   | A
Japan   | B
Ireland | A
Ireland | B
France  | A
France  | B
```

Any ideas on pythonic way to do this? Sorry about the terribly vague title. 
Cheers :)

Comment: Why do you want to duplicate values?  What is your end goal? Seems like ProductType is not an important column.

Comment: Hi, I'm not duplicating productType, but duplicating country so a listed country will have both product A and product B.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [pd.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.melt.html), as follows:

```
df['A'] = 'A'
df['B'] = 'B'
pd.melt(df, id_vars='Country', value_vars=['A', 'B']).sort_values('Country')
```

Answer (score 4):

You could try something like this to build a new datafame with constructor using `product` from itertools.

```
from itertools import product
pd.DataFrame(product(df['Country'].unique(), df['ProductType'].unique()), columns=['Country','ProductType'])
```

Output:

```
   Country ProductType
0      USA           A
1      USA           B
2    China           A
3    China           B
4    Japan           A
5    Japan           B
6  Ireland           A
7  Ireland           B
8   France           A
9   France           B
```

Comment: TypeError: data argument can't be an iterator

Comment: What version of python are you using? and what verison of pandas?

Comment: Python 3.7.1, Pandas '0.23.4'

Answer (score 2):

In pandas you can do with `MultiIndex`

```
pd.MultiIndex.from_product(list(map(set,df.values.T.tolist()))).to_frame()
Out[1148]: 
                 0  1
France  A   France  A
        B   France  B
China   A    China  A
        B    China  B
Japan   A    Japan  A
        B    Japan  B
USA     A      USA  A
        B      USA  B
Ireland A  Ireland  A
        B  Ireland  B
```